# What is meaning of a Kubernetes Native Java stack?

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus

What is meaning of Quarkus Tag line (A Kubernetes Native Java stack)

```
A Kubernetes Native Java stack tailored for OpenJDK HotSpot and GraalVM, crafted from the best of breed Java libraries and standards. (https://quarkus.io)
```

Does this means Quarkus Project deploy on Kubernetes or Container Service made on Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means it has been designed with Kubernetes and more generally containers in minds.

That means a couple of things:

- density: we want to improve the density of the Java applications in container by reducing the memory usage;
- fast startup: we need to be able to start fast, be it for auto-scaling or for serverless workload;
- we also need to be container-friendly: this is mostly about providing the necessary tools to easily deploy in a cloud environment.

That being said, it also runs perfectly well on a physical server or on whatever you want to host it. It's just that the container world brings some additional constraints.

Comment: So is that mean that we still have to create the image and the corresponding K8s resources by hand? Or is Quarkus help with this, like creating default pod template or something like that?